# jQuery ajax returns error but data being added to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently trying to store data into a database via `ajax`.
This works fine but the ajax always returns `"error"` even if the php code has been executing fine.

Javascript

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url:ajaxurl,
    data: { game:game, variation:variation, player:player, win:win }, 
    success: function(data){ 
        alert('success'); 
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error');
     }
});
```

PHP

```
    <?php

include('connectdb.php');

function addNewMatch() {

    $game = $_POST['game'];
    $variation = $_POST['variation'];
    $date = time();
    $player = $_POST['player'];
    $win = $_POST['win'];

    $queryMatch = "INSERT INTO pd_match VALUES (
        NULL,
        '".$game."',
        '".$variation."',
        '".$date."',
        '".$player."',
        '".$win."'
        )";

    $doQueryMatch = mysql_query($queryMatch);
    if (!$doQueryMatch) { return (false); } else { echo 'success'; }

} // end function addNewMatch

addNewMatch();

?>
```

As I said, it works fine but ajax is returning the `alert("error")`.
I must be missing somthing.

(It's done locally on localhost)

Comment: What is the output of your PHP script?

Comment: You might be returning wrong value from your php script. Post your complete php code

Comment: There is no output.  But even with out echo "success"; it didn't work.

Comment: success and error is based on HTTP status code.. should be 200.

Comment: @Miss Chetan Gawai: I edited the PHP code and entered the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax you shouldn't use

```
 <form method="POST" action="phpfile.php">
```

And if you are wrapping the Ajax function inside a `.on('click')` or `.click` event your buttun should be button type button instead of button type submit, like this:

```
  <button type="button"></button>
```

I havn't seen your HTML but usually when I have a problem like this it's because of that.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

and let us know what error you are getting.

Comment: it would be better if you include one more property in your ajax call `contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8"` and check for the error again.

Comment: It didn't change anything.  I think I'm missing something on the php. Does the php file needs a html header (doctype,html,...) or anything else?  Currently the php file is only including the connection to the database and doing the query.  THX for your help